# GeoTIFF gets pixelated when rendering on GeoServer?

Tags: qgis, raster, geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to render an 8 bit GeoTIFF (4 Band) on GeoServer and I am having troubles rendering the image on an WMS service.

When I zoom out the image, it gets pixelated:

[image: pixelated raster at 1:100000]

Below, it is the same GeoTiff in QGIS with same scale (1:100000)

[image: Same raster at 1:100000 o QGIS]

The image rendered by GeoServer is extremely pixelated. I tried tweaking the configuration but I could not reach the same level of quality as it is shown in QGIS.

The version of GeoServer we are using is the 2.2.4. Could someone give me a hint about what may be causing such pixelation on GeoServer?

Comment: That version of GeoServer is too old, if it does not work there is no chance you'll get a fix. Two things you might try: rebuild the overviews of that file using gdal_translate and gdaladdo, or upgrade GeoServer to 2.11

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255122/4-band-geotiff-gets-pixelated-when-rendering-on-geoserver#comment402348_255122) by Andrea Aime, try the following:

- Upgrading GeoServer to its current version, as yours is old (see [here](http://geoserver.org/download/)).
- Rebuild GeoTiff's pyramids/overviews. For example, using [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) (GDAL ADD Overview).